# How do I properly install CouchDB using build-couchdb? 

Tags: build, couchdb, ubuntu-11.10

I'm trying CouchDB on Ubuntu 11.10. Several tests were failing, so I followed [this article's advice](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.couchdb.user/16292) and tried to install from [build-couchdb](https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb), but I'm getting some nasty errors trying to start **couchdb** after a successful build.

1. Does anyone know what this crash report means?
2. Does anyone know why 1.0.1 would be installed, and not the latest build version 1.1.0?

Thanks!

---

`$ build/bin/couchdb`

Apache CouchDB 1.0.1 (LogLevel=info) is starting.

=CRASH REPORT==== 8-Jan-2012::22:19:54 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: couch_event_sup:init/1
    pid: <0.80.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{badmatch,
                         {'EXIT',
                             {{badmatch,{error,enoent}},
                              [{couch_log,init,1},
                               {gen_event,server_add_handler,4},
                               {gen_event,handle_msg,5},
                               {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}}},
                     [{couch_event_sup,init,1},
                      {gen_server,init_it,6},
                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
      in function  gen_server:init_it/6
    ancestors: [couch_primary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.79.0>,<0.6.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 377
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 116
  neighbours:

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 8-Jan-2012::22:19:54 ===
     Supervisor: {local,couch_primary_services}
     Context:    start_error
     Reason:     {{badmatch,{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,enoent}},
                                     [{couch_log,init,1},
                                      {gen_event,server_add_handler,4},
                                      {gen_event,handle_msg,5},
                                      {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}}},
                  [{couch_event_sup,init,1},
                   {gen_server,init_it,6},
                   {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
     Offender:   [{pid,undefined},
                  {name,couch_log},
                  {mfargs,{couch_log,start_link,[]}},
                  {restart_type,permanent},
                  {shutdown,brutal_kill},
                  {child_type,worker}]

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 8-Jan-2012::22:19:54 ===
     Supervisor: {local,couch_server_sup}
     Context:    start_error
     Reason:     shutdown
     Offender:   [{pid,undefined},
                  {name,couch_primary_services},
                  {mfargs,{couch_server_sup,start_primary_services,[]}},
                  {restart_type,permanent},
                  {shutdown,infinity},
                  {child_type,supervisor}]

=CRASH REPORT==== 8-Jan-2012::22:19:54 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: application_master:init/4
    pid: <0.31.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {bad_return,
                        {{couch_app,start,
                             [normal,
                              ["/etc/couchdb/default.ini",
                               "/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},
                         {'EXIT',
                             {{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},
                              [{couch_server_sup,start_server,1},
                               {application_master,start_it_old,4}]}}}}
      in function  application_master:init/4
    ancestors: [<0.30.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.32.0>,normal}]
    links: [<0.30.0>,<0.7.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 987
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 156
  neighbours:

=INFO REPORT==== 8-Jan-2012::22:19:54 ===
    application: couch
    exited: {bad_return,{{couch_app,start,
                                    [normal,
                                     ["/etc/couchdb/default.ini",
                                      "/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},
                         {'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},
                                  [{couch_server_sup,start_server,1},
                                   {application_master,start_it_old,4}]}}}}
    type: temporary

Comment: I did it on 11 a while back with apt-get.  Is it a fresh server, or might you have some conflicting programs?

Comment: Thank you - it looks like there is a conflict, but I'm confused as to why after removing and purging couchdb through apt-get. It looks like I still have some artifacts left behind from the initial install from apt-get, and have posted the question here http://serverfault.com/questions/348044/how-do-i-completely-remove-all-references-to-couchdb-from-ubuntu-11-10. If you could shed some light on that, that would be great!

Comment: You running the wrong binary. `build-couchdb` by default compiles CouchDB-1.1.1. The first row in your log says `Apache CouchDB 1.0.1`.

Comment: Remember to prepend `./` to run a command from the current folder. In your case it should probably be `./build/bin/couchdb`.

Comment: Marcello, you were right. And thank you for answering on ServerFault. If you answer here instead of comment, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcello is right in his comment. The log indicates that you are somehow (I'm not sure how) running version 1.0.1 but Build CouchDB would be building version 1.1.1.

Perhaps you could update your question with the output of these commands?

1. `pwd`
2. `./build/bin/couchdb`

Comment: Being explicit and making sure to purge any existing binaries solved it. http://serverfault.com/a/348082/106402